# Flask-SQLAlchemy loop transaction

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a wallet balance management system. I use Flask-SQLAlchemy with Python 3.8.
In this case I need to add multiple products in a loop (I have simplified the function).
For each added product I first create a transaction line, then I create a product line in different tables.

After completing the loop I reduce the total price from the wallet.
I check that the new balance is more than 0, otherwise I cancel the transactions (All the added lines and the wallet action).

Now the loop portion works just fine. But the `user.balance = user.balance - price` does not get executed. `user` is a database object that I get from `get_user_details`.

There is no errors.
What am I missing?

```
def put_data(data, pproduct, price):


    user = get_user_details()
    
    multi_product = data.get(MULTI_PR, 1) if data.get(MULTI_PR, 1) != -1 else 1
    product_number = int(get_product_num(pproduct))

    # Start transaction
    db.session.begin()

    for index, product_id in enumerate(list(range(product_number, product_number + multi_product))):
        transaction_id = gen_trn_uid()
        transaction = transactions.Transaction()
        transaction.transaction_id = transaction_id
        transaction.status = "init"
        transaction.user_id = user.id
        transaction.sum = price / multi_product
        transaction.transaction_date = datetime.now()

        db.session.add(transaction)
        db.session.flush()

        product = game_products.ProductForm()
        product.product = pproduct
        product.data = str(data)
        product.status = 'init'
        product.time = datetime.now()
        product.user_id = user.id
        games_form.product_number = product_id
        product.transaction_id = transaction.id

        db.session.add(product)
        db.session.flush()

    user.balance = user.balance - price
    db.session.flush()

    if user.balance < 0:
        db.session.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(HTTPStatus.PAYMENT_REQUIRED, 'insufficient balance',
                            name='Err 713')
    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

session.flush() communicates a series of operations to the database (insert, update, delete). The database maintains them as pending operations in a transaction. The changes aren't persisted permanently to disk, or visible to other transactions until the database receives a COMMIT for the current transaction (which is what session.commit() does).

can you try to commit first then use user.balance = user.balance - price ?

something like this.

```
def put_data(data, pproduct, price):


    user = get_user_details()
    
    multi_product = data.get(MULTI_PR, 1) if data.get(MULTI_PR, 1) != -1 else 1
    product_number = int(get_product_num(pproduct))

    # Start transaction
    db.session.begin()

    for index, product_id in enumerate(list(range(product_number, product_number + multi_product))):
        transaction_id = gen_trn_uid()
        transaction = transactions.Transaction()
        transaction.transaction_id = transaction_id
        transaction.status = "init"
        transaction.user_id = user.id
        transaction.sum = price / multi_product
        transaction.transaction_date = datetime.now()

        db.session.add(transaction)
        db.session.flush()

        product = game_products.ProductForm()
        product.product = pproduct
        product.data = str(data)
        product.status = 'init'
        product.time = datetime.now()
        product.user_id = user.id
        games_form.product_number = product_id
        product.transaction_id = transaction.id

        db.session.add(product)
        db.session.flush()

  
    db.session.commit()
    user.balance = user.balance - price
    
    if user.balance < 0:
        db.session.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(HTTPStatus.PAYMENT_REQUIRED, 'insufficient balance',
                            name='Err 713')
    db.session.flush()
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: I understand what you explained, that is why my commit is after the user.balance update. 
I need the balance in the DB be updated only if all the objects are writen as well, and if the balance update fails I need all the other updates to fails as well. 

What you suggest is to finish my transaction and then create a new one.

Comment: Yes i thought of it at first. It is correct only if these transactions effect user.balance. If not. It is not related to the problem. One thing came up to my mind is maybe user.balance  type is not incompatible with integer. You should check the incoming data for user.balance bu debugging the app.